# MERN+gql project; Heroku deployment build failing at install script because "can't cd to server"

Tags: heroku, apollo, mern, mongodb-atlas, gql

In the process of converting a project using a mysql db and an express server into one with the same concept (a free online game search application) but in a MERN+gql framework.  After creating my gql schemas and testing them in my localhost, I attempted to push the project to Heroku in the hopes of connecting continuous deployment as I worked on the front end.

I have been unable to deploy to Heroku because each time I attempt a push to Heroku the build fails on my "install" scrip...a script that I have successfully used before in deploying MERN+gql projects on Heroku. ‍‍♀️

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > game-on@1.0.0 install
remote:        > cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: cd: can't cd to server
remote:        npm notice 
remote:        npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.9.2 -> 10.3.0
remote:        npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.3.0>
remote:        npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.3.0` to update!
remote:        npm notice 
remote:        npm ERR! code 2
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_31774fbf
remote:        npm ERR! command failed
remote:        npm ERR! command sh -c cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /tmp/npmcache.j8gTf/_logs/2024-01-18T00_51_37_422Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

I have gone through the code to check for  typos and inconsistancies but have found nothing.  I'm really befuddled because it works as expected on my local host; it's just the deployment that's giving me trouble.

one-by-one I've...
-double checked the environment variables in Heroku.
-looked carefully over my code for typos or inconsistencies.
-updated the npm v to 10.3.0 as the message from the build log suggested.
-tried re-installing the dependancies manually.
-tried breaking the install script in my root package.json
`"install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i"`
into three separate scripts

```
"install": "npm run install-server && npm run install-client",
  "install-server": "cd server && npm i",
  "install-client": "cd client && npm i",
```

-banged my head against the wall
...all to receive the exact same error message.  HAAAALP!

Comment: Well, do you have a `server/` directory to `cd` into? Is it called `server` _exactly_ (not `Server` or something)? Remember, we only know what you tell us. We have no idea what's in your repository.

Comment: yes, I have a directory called server with a lowercase "s".
There's a package.json at the root level with the install script in question, a server directory with its own package.json/dependencies and a client directory with  its own package.json/dependencies...